# How to add a menu tab to frequently asked questions?

Tags: drupal-6

I have installed the faq and faq_ask module.
The faq_ask module adds a navigation link of 'ask a question'.
When I click on it, it displays a form to the user to ask a question.

The faq module adds a navigation link of frequently asked questions.
When I click on it, it displays the questions and answers list. It contains two tabs 'list' and 'order'.
I have added the third tab of 'ask a question' and Now I want to display the ask a question form on this tab.

**EDIT:**

`function test_menu() {

 $items = array();

$items['faq/ask_question'] =array(

    'title' => 'Ask a question',

    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',

    'page arguments' => array("test_ask_question"),

    'access callback' => TRUE,

    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,

  );

 return $items;

}`


Any Idea about this???

Comment: I edited my question and post my code for adding the tab. Now what should I code in test_ask_question to display the form of faq_ask module?

Comment: my question is not how to display the tab. My question is that how should I display the ask_question form on this tab?

Comment: You should make sure that the path faq/ask_question is not being hijacked by some other module, other than that, the code looks good to me. Try to flush your cache so your menu router gets recreated.